# Extend the "find users by OpenID, Email etc" tool to find matching profile pictures

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, profile-picture

We have a persistent troll on Physics.SE who uses the Opera-mini proxy farms to (unsuccessfully<sup>1</sup>) disguise his/her endless unregistered socks. However, I believe that he/she has many fewer gravitars than accounts.

Being able to ask for other account using the same profile pictures would make it easier to collect related accounts together.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some people's poor writing/thinking/punctuation/formatting skills are highly diagnostic.

Comment: s/he\/she/their/g

Comment: @hjpotter92 I know that an increasing number of professionals accept that substitution but it still feels wrong to me.

Comment: He/She, lgbt, m.o.u.s.e.